# Can not switch language with keyboard

Tags: 13.10, gnome, language-support, locale

I have added the locale language at installation. But now, When I change the language from toolbar, It still types English. System is installed freshly and has latest updates.

**Edit:**

I have removed the *Persian* and Added *Persian (with Persian keyboard)*. Now I can switch the language throw toolbar, But when I change it via <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> , The language name on toolbar changes but the input language still is English.

- I have Ubuntu-Gnome 13.10
- Language: Persian (fa)

What is the solution?

Comment: The Persian was there, But I removed it and added "Persian (With Persian keyboard"
But still have another problem (I'll add it to the question)

Comment: @user68186: I think its not duplicate now. My problem is changed now.

Answer (score 1):

## Updated for Ubuntu 18.04

Click on the icons on top right corner and select **Screwdriver & Wrench** icon at the bottom of the drop-down menu. Then select the **Devices** from the left panel. Then select the **Keyboard** from the left panel. This will bring you to the table of keyboard shortcuts.

Scroll down to the **Typing** section and find two entries:

- Switch to next input source <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>
- Switch to previous input source <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

Select **Switch to next input source** and follow the instructions on the screen and press the keyboard shortcut you want to use such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Select **Switch to previous input source** and follow the instructions on the screen and press the keyboard shortcut you want to use such as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

## Original Answer

Click on the power/Gear icon on top right corner and select **System Settings...** Then select the **Text Entry** icon under Personal. Make sure Persian is listed. If not, add it by clicking on the + sign.

I find it hard to use any combination with <kbd>Alt</kbd> as it brings up the HUD. To change this return to **Text Entry** as before and click on the space under **Switch to next source using:** where it says Alt+Shift and enter another combination such as <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Next click on the space under **Switch to previous source using** and enter another combination such as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Hope this helps